# Crop package, want three outside edges to have bleed

Tags: printing, crop, booklet, bleed

I have formatted a document for printing, and the printer is saying that I need a bleed of 0.125' on the outside three edges.

I am printing a booklet (using `booklet'), so the outside edges look like:

```
_______________
|xxxxxx|xxxxxx|
|x     |     x|
|x     |     x|
|x     |     x|
|xxxxxx|xxxxxx|
|------|------|
```

where the "x"s are the part where the bleed margin should be.

To do this, I am using the package `crop`, which seems to do exactly what I need it to do, which is provide outside edge around the page I made, without me having to fiddle with rearranging anything inside the pages (for woe is me if I do).

However, `crop`'s only options for providing the margin aren't working for me, as I only need the bleed on the three outside edges.

Following the documentation, I was able to make a `left` option, which is close.  I do this by adding a `crop.cfg` file with the following definition:

```
\newcount\CROP@offset
\newcommand*\CROP@left{%
    \CROP@offset=\ifx\CROP@@\empty\z@\else\CROP@@\fi
    \voffset\stockheight
    \advance\voffset-\paperheight
    \voffset.5\voffset
    \def\CROP@every{%
        \count@\c@page
            \advance\count@\CROP@offset

            \ifodd\count@
                \hoffset0pt
            \else
                \hoffset\stockwidth
                \advance\hoffset-\paperwidth
        \fi
    }%
}
```

This sort of does what I want it to do, except that it is

```
_______________
|xxxxxx|xxxxxx|
|x     |x     |
|x     |x     |
|x     |x     |
|xxxxxx|xxxxxx|
|------|------|
```

The `\CROP@every` line, from what I understand, should update every page and render even and odd pages differently; I made this by copying the package's own `mount2` definition by changing it for my purposes.   However, it isn't.

Below is a minimum working example (plus the `crop.cfg` file): I've left in the `booklet` commands, as maybe those are relevant.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\AtBeginDocument{\setpdftargetpages}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[noinfo,pdflatex,cam,cross,width=5.625in,height=8.75in,left]{crop}
 
\usepackage[noprint,1to1]{booklet} % initial runs for ToC and index
%\usepackage[print,1to1]{booklet} \nofiles % final printing run
\usepackage{twoup}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{5.5in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{8.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.3in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{4.5in}

\setpdftargetpages
\pagespersignature{120}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-24]
\end{document}
```

How do I need to define a new `crop` option so that it actually changes behavior on even/odd pages?

Thanks

Comment: Add `twoside` to your `\documentclass` options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the magnitudes of the cropping, but the addition of `twoside` is needed to get the even/odd feature in play in the document margins.  However, for the cropping margins (bleed) to come into play, I had to use the package macro `\@CROP@user@a` to change `\leftskip` and `rightskip` every page.  This macro is executed every page, unlike `\CROP@left` which is only executed once. (I skipped `.123in` rather than `.125in`, so that you can confirm the crop mark exists just shy of the paper edge)

Also, the left and right skips only affect the crop marks, not the underlying document, so you will have to use the document margins to compensate, probably with `\evensidemargin` and `\oddsidemargin`, which I have attempted to do here (the `50pt` value, which represents the binding margin, may need adjustment).

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,twoside]{article}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{crop.cfg}
\DeclareOption{left}{\AtBeginDocument{\CROP@left}}

\newcount\CROP@offset
\CROP@offset=1
\newcommand*\CROP@left{%
    \voffset\stockheight
    \advance\voffset-\paperheight
    \voffset.5\voffset
    \def\CROP@user@a{%
        \count@\c@page
            \advance\count@\CROP@offset
            \ifodd\count@
              \leftskip=.123in
              \rightskip=-.123in
            \else
              \leftskip=-.0in
              \rightskip=.0in
            \fi
    }%
}
\end{filecontents*}

\AtBeginDocument{\setpdftargetpages}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[noinfo,pdflatex,cam,cross,width=5.625in,height=8.75in,left]{crop}


\usepackage[noprint,1to1]{booklet} % initial runs for ToC and index
%\usepackage[print,1to1]{booklet} \nofiles % final printing run
\usepackage{twoup}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{5.5in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{8.5in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.25in}
\setlength{\textheight}{8.in}
\setlength{\footskip}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.3in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{4.5in}

\setpdftargetpages
\pagespersignature{120}

\evensidemargin=\dimexpr-50pt+.125in
\oddsidemargin= \dimexpr+50pt-1in

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-24]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried that right after posting, but as you see in your images, it always has a zero margin on the left and non-zero margin on the right, as opposed to distinguishing even/odd.

Comment: @RBoston The even/odd pages crop differently in my picture, not the same.  However, it is true that the margin is never zero exactly.

Comment: Maybe it isn't rendering properly for me, but I see in all cases the left "+"s are along the left border, while the right "+"s are about 1/4 inch from the right border, and all about 1/4 inch from the top/bottom

Comment: @RBoston My confusion.  You not only need the document to adjust its margins, but the crop marks must also change, relative to the paper.  And in my MWE, the bleed margin is always to the right.  Do I understand better?

Comment: Yes. I may have been confusing terminology.  The bleed should always be on the outside.

Comment: @RBoston I will delete my answer, unless and until I can address this.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @RBoston Please see my revision

Comment: That did the trick!  For the record, I was able to make it work without the `everypage` package.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @RBoston You are right.  That is vestigial from a prior attempt.  I will remove it.  Glad it could work for you.